# Access 2010 file dialog call from VBA not working

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am calling a filedialog but for some reason I am getting the error in the screenshot.  The code calling it is:
[image: Runtime Error]

```
Private Sub cmdSelectFile_Click()
  Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

   With objDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
      MsgBox "No file selected."
    Else
      txtFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Anyone able to say what the error is?  References has both the office 14 object library and the access 14 library included

Thanks

Comment: See the solution I found posted below

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare variable first :

```
Private Sub cmdSelectFile_Click()
Dim objDialog As Office.FileDialog
Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With objDialog
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Show
  If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No file selected."
  Else
     txtFilePath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried adding the dim statement in-gives an error that it is an user defined type

Comment: unfortunately I cannot test it on 2010, but it works on Office 2013 Pro

Answer (score 0):

The library seemed t not pick up the msofiledialogpicker- changed it to msofiledialogopen and it worked fine.  Not sure why- it worked with picker on one machine but not across the network on other machines, still this solution did work.